# Graphing floor and ceiling functions

Tags: graphics

[image: How do I graph both of these?]

How do I graph both of these on Mathematica?

This is what I wrote:

```
Plot[{Floor[x] + Floor[x]}, {Floor[x] - Floor[x]}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

But this is what I get

> Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of {x,-10,10}) beyond position 2 in Plot[{Floor[x]+Floor[x]},{Floor[x]-Floor[x]},{x,-10,10}]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot[{Floor[x] + Ceiling[x],Ceiling[x] - Floor[x]}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

but since we need to demenstrate some discontinus points,the plot need to be improved.

**Edit**

Using some advice by @BobHanlon

```
Show[Plot[Ceiling[x] - Floor[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
   ExclusionsStyle -> {None, {AbsolutePointSize[8], Black}}, 
   Exclusions -> All, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}] /. 
  Point[pts_] :> {Point@pts, White, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point@pts}, 
 DiscretePlot[Ceiling[x] - Floor[x], {x, -4, 4}, Filling -> None, 
  ExtentSize -> None]]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot[Ceiling[x] + Floor[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
   ExclusionsStyle -> {None, {AbsolutePointSize[8]}}, 
   Exclusions -> All, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}] /. 
  Point[pts_] :> {Point@pts, White, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point@pts}, 
 DiscretePlot[Ceiling[x] + Floor[x], {x, -4, 4}, Filling -> None, 
  ExtentSize -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[{Floor[x] + Ceiling[x], Ceiling[x] - Floor[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Red, Blue}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon  when `x` is a integer, `Ceiling[x] - Floor[x]` equal to `0`,  other wise equal to `1`, I want to plot this.

Comment: `Show[Plot[{Floor[x] + Ceiling[x], Ceiling[x] - Floor[x]}, {x, -10, 10}], DiscretePlot[{Floor[x] + Ceiling[x], Ceiling[x] - Floor[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, Filling -> None]]`

Comment: Or more succinctly, `Show[#[{Floor[x] + Ceiling[x], Ceiling[x] - Floor[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, Filling -> None] & /@ {Plot, DiscretePlot}]`